# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' при использовании русских тэгов в XML файле

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

Получаю следующую ошибку при использовании русских тэгов в XML файле `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

При парсинге XML файла использую Python3 + библиотеку ElementTree.

```
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for elem in root:
    name = elem.find("Владелец_ИСПД").text
    phone = elem.find("phone").text
    email = elem.find("email").text
    date = elem.find("date").text
    rows.append({"Владелец_ИСПД": name,
                 "phone": phone,
                 "email": email,
                 "date": date,})
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
```

Структура XML-файла:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
      <name>f</name>
      <Администратор>
        <Полное_имя>ФИО1</Полное_имя>
        <Должность_1>Инженер1</Должность_1>
        <Телефон>12345</Телефон>
        <Почта>user1@mail.ru</Почта>
      </Администратор>
      <Администратор>
        <Полное_имя>ФИО2</Полное_имя>
        <Должность_1>Инженер2</Должность_1>
        <Телефон>123456</Телефон>
        <Почта>user2@mail.ru</Почта>
      </Администратор>
      <test>fg</test>
      <Категория>
        <Item>ИУС</Item>
      </Категория>
      <Владелец_ИСПД>МГ</Владелец_ИСПД>
      <ИС_Назначение>Программный комплекс</ИС_Назначение>
      <Оценка_не_проводилась>
        <Item>Нет</Item>
      </Оценка_не_проводилась>
      <Причина_отправки_в_архив>
        <Item>Карточку ИС можно удалить</Item>
      </Причина_отправки_в_архив>
      <ИС_Наименование>Программный комплекс авт системы</ИС_Наименование>
      <Наименование>"METR5" Алтайского ЛПУМГ</Наименование>
      <Филиал>
        <Наименование>ЛПУ МГ Алтайское</Наименование>
      </Филиал>
    </root>
```

При выполнении данного кода происходит ошибка:

```
name = elem.find("Владелец_ИСПД").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Есть предположение, что проблема может быть в кодировке. Питон может не видеть русские символы и поэтому возвращает пустое значение. Может быть есть у кого-то решение?
Надеюсь на вашу помощь, спасибо!

Comment: А вы проверяли - в какой кодировке у вас сам `XML` и в какой кодировке ваш питоновский скрипт? По-нормальному у питона `utf-8` кодировка родная.

Comment: @CrazyElf В XML-файле указано явно значение кодировки. Скрипт питона тоже должен быть автоматически utf-8. Не могу разобраться в чем проблема

Comment: У вас операционная система какая? Под windows файл с питоновским кодом может оказаться в любой кодировке - utf8, cp866, cp1251.

Comment: @CrazyElf Операционная система Windows. Решил переформатировать XML файл, теперь при попытке записи данных из тэгов в базу данных записывается пустое значение (Null).

Comment: Откройте ваш XML каким-то редактором, который понимает кодировки. А то мало ли что в самом XML написано, это не гарантия, что сам файл в той же кодировке записан. Да хоть в Far Manager. Или там в Notepad++. Надо проверить, какая кодировка там на самом деле.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, действительно при открытии в Wordpad символы не распознаются. Как корректнее всего изменить кодировку этого файла?

Comment: WordPad использует кодировку cp1251, так что это говорит только о том, что файл не в виндовой кодировке. Он может быть в utf8, а может и не быть. Нужно брать редактор, который умеет переключать кодировки. Найти в нём какая кодировка у файла на самом деле, скопировать текст, переключить кодировку в utf-8, вставить текст и сохранить. Если дело вообще в кодировке.